# Chrome loses scroll position on Google search results

Tags: google-chrome, scrolling, google-search

Try this:

1. Go to [google.com](https://www.google.com/)
2. Search something like `stackoverflow`
3. Scroll down and click on the last link, for me it was Alexa
4. Press the back button, it's okay if the page didn't finish loading
5. Chrome has lost the last scroll position, your scroll bar should be at the top now

I am on the latest non-dev version of Chrome (Version 27.0.1453.116 m) with no plugins/extensions. This also does the same thing on Incognito mode.

If for step 3, instead of clicking on a search result but the search page numbers, this does not happen. Clicking on the number two, then clicking the back button does save your scroll position as before on the previous page.

By search page numbers, I mean the numbers listed at the bottom of the page:

[image]

```
                    ^ Clicking on the number two
```

This also completely doesn't happen on other websites such as wikipedia or stackoverflow. If you follow a link on wikipedia and click the back button, your scroll position is saved.

Chrome also seems to be refreshing the Google Search results every time I press the back button. The screen flashes as if it was a refresh.

I would like to stop chrome from doing this.

What should I try next?

Comment: Personally, I would report this to Google. Open `chrome://chrome/` and click the FEEDBACK button. Alternatively, use one of their support forums.

Comment: Just added it [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/windows/R9m2m-XdjgI), if I get any fixes rather than an update, I'll post it here.

Comment: You might check if disabling Google instant fixes this.

Comment: Disabling Google instant does not change anything.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior. Where exactly should I click? *"If for step 3, instead of clicking on a search result but the search page numbers"* <- what does this mean? I'm on Chrome 27.0.1453.110.

Comment: If instead of clicking on the search result, the number is clicked (check the edit), the scroll position is saved properly.